# Creating a Command Line Argument System for Embedded Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a main python3 file as follows:

```
import additionalfunctions

userIn = input("Select Function and command line arguments: ")
```

'additionalfunctions.py' is as follows:

```
def arbitraryfunction(arg):
   print("you entered the value: " + str(arg))
```

The issue I am facing is that I need to select this function with with the 'input()' in the main python file, as well as pass the one argument to it. Does anyone know how to parse the variable 'userIn' in order to select and run a function, and pass arguments to it?

Any help you can give would be much appreciated!

Comment: That would be `import additionalfunctions`, unless you actually have a file named `py.py` in your package.

Comment: Typically, you build your own `dict` that maps user-input strings to function names. The input string can be the same as the function name, but that's an implementation detail of your exposed interface, rather than requiring the user to know about internal function names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to High-Octane answer, which is totally right, once you have the command line parameters, you can use `exec()` to run the selected function and pass the arguments to it. Try this based on your own code:

```
def arbitraryfunction(arg):
   print("you entered the value: " + str(arg))

allowed_functions = ['arbitraryfunction']

# write "arbitraryfunction 0" or similar when asked
userIn = input("Select Function and command line arguments: ")
args = userIn.split(" ")

if len(args) >= 2:
    fun = args[0]
    arg = args[1]

if fun in allowed_functions:
    exec(fun + "(" + str(arg) + ")")
else:
    print("Function not found. Please try again")
```

Then,you have to import additionalfunctions (I included it into the same script for simplicity) like this:

```
from additionalfunctions import *
```

**Disclaimer: This should not be used in any production sensitive environment as it can execute malicious scripts.**

Comment: This is extremely insecure. You are not doing any input validation. Basically a user could execute arbitrary code on your machine extremely easily. Please don't use `exec` and at least do some sanitation. @High-Octane's answer is much better in that regard.

Comment: You're totally right! I guess it is just an exercise. In fact, I don't see the point of doing that at all. But, as a mere exercise to learn... it's funny!

Comment: It's not a great service to the community to lead users in the wrong direction, even if it's "funny". If that person is a novice, they won't be able to tell if this is the right way to solve the problem. I would at least give a warning that this should not be used in production.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default package `argparse`

And create a function like below.

**Code:**

```
import argparse
#>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ARGUMENT PARSING <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

def args():
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-A','--Arg1',type=int,help='I am Argument 1',required=False)

parser.add_argument('-B','--Arg2',type=str,help='I am Argument 2',required=True)

parser.add_argument('-C','--Arg3',type=str,help='I am Argument 3',required=True)


args = parser.parse_args()

print("PARSING ARGUMENTS COMPLETED")
```

argparse documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html